Is there a way i could turn this variable into an operator
t = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"]
t2 = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"]

number1 = int(t[randint(0, 9)])  
number2 = int(t2[randint(0, 9)])
operator = buttonbox ("What do you want your questions to be?",choices = ["+","*","/","-"])
question = integerbox("What is " + str(number1) + operator + str(number2) + " ?")
    
if question == number1 operator number2:

I was expecting it to turn the choice from the operator into a proper variable

Each operator has a functional equivalent in the operator module. For example,
from operator import add

assert add(3, 5) == 3 + 5

You can build a dictionary mapping strings to such functions.
ops = {"+": add}
assert ops["+"](3, 5) == 3 + 5

